# Is this a sign of heap fragmentation?

Tags: c++

To test if my object had a memory leak, I instanced it 10000 times and deleted it 10000 times. After, my program was using about 500kb more. I do not think my object is leaking though.

Thanks

Comment: What operating system?  How do you know your "program was using about 500kb more"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux at least, the C library does not release memory back to the OS just because you call `delete`.  It puts the memory on a "free list" inside your process.  So if you are using a command like `top` or `cat /proc/XXX/status` to measure the virtual memory use, you will see the size consumed by everything in your process including that free list.

The C library only releases memory back to the system when you `free` or `delete` a "large" object.  The definition of "large" is something like 128K bytes.

I suspect Windows, Mac, etc. work similarly but I do not know for sure.

So the short answer to your question is "No, not necessarily".

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your class actually contains and does, what you describe can happen, even if your class doesn't leak.

Some standard library implementations allocate class like `std::string` from memory pools.

You should use an actual leak checker like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) instead of your test runs.